# Remote workers login via Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, windows-8, azure-active-directory, domaincontroller

I have a very small office with 2 Windows 8 machines, and people work remotely. Because we use Office 365 and Azure we're already setup with Azure Active Directory (AD). When users VPN in to the office they can use with AD account. However, I wonder if it is possible to allow the on premise Win-8 machines to log in using their AD account? We have no on premise servers (excluding NAS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Windows Azure AD currently does not support domain joined machines and machine/user authentication.  It is different in this way than Windows Server Active Directory.

Windows Azure AD currently is centered around user authentication for web based applications.